# how to remove empty or null tags from xml via xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

Below is my xml; i am generating this xml through xsd by using datastage ETL tool, now my requirement is in the below xml i don't have data for note  tag even though i am getting note tag in the xml which i don't want to display in my xml; could you please suggest me how to remove that tag

```
      <term
           rid="6662c0f2.e1b1ec6c.a1fk8pal9.8hqrjus.6af65b.8lr7d8vtg6ibohsre1bni"
           name="Test Term" longDescription="  " status="CANDIDATE"
           example="  " type="NONE" isModifier="false" workflowStatus="Published">
           <parentCategory identity="Test Category_Edit" rid="6662c0f2.ee6a64fe.a1fk62v4g.c0kd2bc.0rjqdm.feik8m3int29gfigeshsp"/>
           <replacedByTerm identity="Test Category_Edit::TestTerm 6" rid="6662c0f2.e1b1ec6c.a1fka7kac.1khu23o.2u72oe.bhpdj3dkdshb026mkdqks"/>
           <referencedByCategories>
                <categoryRef identity="Test RuleBook Category"
                     rid="6662c0f2.ee6a64fe.a1fkahnel.nso45vp.cns86c.758gjtic3rakunadr1v1k"
                     xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                <categoryRef identity="Test ACE Category"
                     rid="6662c0f2.ee6a64fe.a1fkahnel.nso4pkh.3pmfh7.ccc8kcdsml2s8hdhtld7k"
                     xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
           </referencedByCategories>
           <assignedAssets>
                <BIReportMemberRef
                     reportModel="GAS Reporting - Detail"
                     reportModelNameSpace="sat1msmap054.nao.global.gmacfs.com\Public Folders\Auto Finance Packages\GAS Reporting - Detail\GAS Reporting - Detail\"
                     reportCollection="DIM_CONTRACT_ORA"
                     reportCollectionNameSpace="GAS Reporting - Detail/GAS - Database View"
                     reportMember="TERM"
                     nameSpace="[GAS - Database View].[DIM_CONTRACT_ORA]"
                     xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
           </assignedAssets>
           <customAttributes>
                <customAttributeValue
                     customAttribute="ERM - General Process Category"
                     value="Advertising and Marketing"
                     xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                <customAttributeValue customAttribute="Changecode"
                     value="Y" xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                <customAttributeValue
                     customAttribute="Test Attribute 1" value="2"
                     xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                <customAttributeValue
                     customAttribute="03. Is Reference Data?"
                     value="Yes" xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                <customAttributeValue
                     customAttribute="06. Data Quality Performed?"
                     value="No" xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
           </customAttributes>
           <relatedTerms>
                <termRef identity="Test Category_Edit::Test Term5"
                     rid="6662c0f2.e1b1ec6c.a1fka7kac.1khv5h5.dmdrre.h0dusknvjnvdde1osbv1s"
                     xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                <termRef identity="Test Category_Edit::TestTerm 7"
                     rid="6662c0f2.e1b1ec6c.a1fka7kac.1khuk2l.erslsg.shh1dj9auomm9p97vr5us"
                     xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
           </relatedTerms>
           <note/>
           <labels>
                <label name="DFS Rulebook" xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                <label name="FR Y-9C H1-B Retail" xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                <label name="DFS - Servicing" xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
           </labels>
           <steward userName="M7HA75" type="USER"/>
      </term>
```

Comment: XSD is not aimed at modifying XML documents, but validating them. Do you actually mean XSL-T (XSL transformations)?

Comment: but i am generating this xml throught xsd only;below is the xsd    <xs:complexType name="noteType">   
   <xs:simpleContent>      
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
     <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="label" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="comment" use="optional"/>
      </xs:extension>
 </xs:simpleContent>  
  </xs:complexType>  
  <xs:complexType name="notesType">
    <xs:sequence> 
   <xs:element type="noteType" name="note" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />  
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

Comment: @123srinu Have you solved this problem? If you have solve it, How have you done?

Answer (score 1):

As @potame said the way is XSL-T .. you could use following XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Above XSL removes all empty tag.